# Coq: proving `P -> ~P -> Q` without `contradiction` tactic?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am learning Coq and I just discovered that it is constructive.

That's one way I can prove that "contradiction implies everything" and it works:

```
Theorem contradiction_implies_anything: forall P Q : Prop, P -> ~P -> Q.
Proof.
  intros P Q p not_p.
  contradiction.
  Qed.
```

Note that no `Q` was **constructed**, so I assume `contradiction` is built-in into the Coq proof engine. It seems to me that otherwise one has to show how `Q` is consructed, and it isn't possible for any `Q`, thus the theorem above can not be proved then. In particular I can not prove the theorem above in the following (pseudo) code:

```
intros P Q p not_p.
introduce P \/ Q. # here I have to construct Q, right?.. that's the point where Coq's "constructivity" becomes an obstruction
introduce ~P \/ Q. # same here
run case analysis on both and figure out that Q must be true.
Qed.
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contradiction` isn't actually necessary here, and there are two main reasons why:

1. `~ P` is a standard library notation for `P -> False`, which means that if you have hypotheses `P` and `~ P`, you can apply `~ P` to `P` to get `False`.
2. The standard library defines `False` like so: `Inductive False : Prop :=.` That means that if you `destruct` a hypothesis of type `False`, the resulting case analysis will have zero cases. That is to say, your proof will be done!

So, to summarize, you can prove your theorem like so:

```
Theorem contradiction_implies_anything: forall P Q : Prop, P -> ~P -> Q.
Proof.
  intros P Q p not_p.
  apply not_p in p.
  destruct p.
Qed.
```

Comment: Interesting. Can I do the `inversion` for the same reason? To get "zero cases" and thus finish my proof?

Comment: I think so, at least that sounds right to me!

Comment: Notice that you can use `exfalso` to replace the current goal with `False`.

Answer (score 1):

In Coq, negation is defined as follows:

```
Inductive False : Prop := 
  (* An inductive proposition with no constructors *). 
Definition not (P : Prop) : Prop := P -> False.
```

The lemma you proved is a consequence of the following more primitive principle:

```
Lemma exfalso (Q : Prop) : False -> Q.
Proof. intros contra. destruct contra. Qed.
```

Intuitively, if we know that an inductive proposition `P` holds and we want to show that some other `Q` holds as well, all we need to do is consider all the constructors that could have been applied to establish `P`. This is what the `destruct` tactic does.  But when `P` is `False`, there are no constructors, so we do not have to do anything.

I like to thing of this situation as follows: it is not the case that this process constructed a proof of `Q`, but rather that we showed there we do not have to construct anything.

Given `exfalso`, it is easy to prove your original statement in more primitive terms (I advice you to walk through this proof to see what is going on!):

```
Goal forall P Q : Prop, P -> ~P -> Q.
Proof.
intros P Q Hyes Hno.
apply exfalso. apply Hno. apply Hyes.
Qed.
```